# VMware causes BSOD on virtual machine boot

Tags: vmware-workstation, windows-8, bsod

I've got VMware 9.1 installed on Windows 8 Pro. I'm trying to run a virtual machine of Fedora 13 created on this computer. It is installed on an external hard drive, and I last opened the vm on a computer at my school running VMware 8 on Windows 7.

Now when I try to boot the vm, I get to the login screen for Fedora, but a second or two after my Windows 8 host OS BSOD's with the error `DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_EQUAL_OR_LESS`.

I can upload error files if someone tells me which might be useful. Any help is much appreciated.

Edit: VMware Workstation 9.1*

Edit2: Before the crash each time the event log indicates `Starting up the Adapter Driver for VMware Virtual Networks.` I'll look into this further.

Comment: what does the event log say?

Comment: That error is almost always a driver issue.. Make sure you have the most up to date versions of all drivers, firmware, etc. Also, VMWare is a company, not software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the machine's network adapter, try to boot.  If successful, you know what the problem is.  Use a different adapter type.

Comment: Yup. VM boots fine without any adapter. Thanks for the advice.